# How to declare anonymous function write in C for PHP extension?

Tags: php, php-extension, php-internals

I have the following code:

```
class Demo
{
    private $data = array();

    public function foo($key, $value)
    {
        $this->data[$key] = function ($c) use ($value) {
            return $c + $value;
        });
    }
}
```

As you can see the `foo` method sets the `$key` using an anonymous function. And it uses the `use($value)` syntax.

How to achieve this in a PHP extension?

Comment: Improved grammar and layout

Comment: What do you want to achieve in your extension?

Comment: Just want to declare an anonymous function for a variable. @hek2mgl

Comment: Meaning your extension exposes a function which will return an anonymous function to the PHP userland?

Comment: Yes right. @hek2mgl  What should i do in PHP extension.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is possible at all.. Let me check that at home. Will give you a feedback..

Comment: @0X07DE I don't think that this possible unless you create the opcode (that what usually the PHP parser creates) of the function in C code and fake the function starting line, source filename etc. (Mind reflection). Why would you do that in an extension? You can simply use the code as above in your question, isn't it?

Comment: @hek2mgl Thanks for the result "that what usually the PHP parser creates". Anyway thank you very much for follow-up this answer : )

Comment: You will need to declare a normal function as a callback (if you start the name with a NUL byte, it will not show up in function lists). Then either return an ordinary function callback or create a closure from it using zend_create_closure, if you have a strict requirement of returning a Closure instance.